# Cocos2d-x 3.0 onTouchMoved not functioning

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am trying to get touch events working in my game and onTouchDown works just fine. My problem arrises with onTouchMoved as, though it doesnt throw me any errors during compiling, it does not seem to be functional.
 I can't seem to find any documentation that helps in this case, and most methods I found online dont seem to work either.

My Code:
LevelOneScene.h

```
class LevelOneScene : public cocos2d::Layer
{
public:
    // there's no 'id' in cpp, so we recommend returning the class instance pointer
    static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();

    // Here's a difference. Method 'init' in cocos2d-x returns bool, instead of returning 'id' in cocos2d-iphone
    virtual bool init();
    void update(float dt);
    // a selector callback
    //void menuCloseCallback(cocos2d::Ref* pSender);
    void changeScene(cocos2d::Ref* pSender);

    //Screen Data
    Point origin;
    Size visibleSize;



    //add Spirtes
    void addShip();
    Ship* ship;
    void addBackground();
    Sprite* background;
    bool onTap(Touch* touch,
               Event* touchEvent);
    // implement the "static create()" method manually
    CREATE_FUNC(LevelOneScene);
private:
    virtual void onEnter();
    virtual void onExit();
    void onTouchMoved(Touch* touch,
                      Event* touchEvent);};
```

LevelOneScene.cpp

```
bool LevelOneScene::onTap(Touch* touch,
                          Event* touchEvent)
{

    CCLOG("Screen was Tapped");
    return 0;

}
void LevelOneScene::onTouchMoved(Touch* touch,
                  Event* touchEvent)
{
    CCLOG("Touch Moved\n");
    ship->stopAllActions();
    auto moveLeft = cocos2d::MoveTo::create(.5, cocos2d::Point(touch->getLocation().x,ship->getPositionY()));
    ship->runAction(moveLeft);

}
void LevelOneScene::update(float dt)
{

}
void LevelOneScene::onExit()
{
    Layer::onExit();
}
void LevelOneScene::onEnter()
{
    Layer::onEnter();
    auto touchListener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
    touchListener->setSwallowTouches(true);
    touchListener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(LevelOneScene::onTap, this);

    touchListener->onTouchMoved = CC_CALLBACK_2(LevelOneScene::onTouchMoved, this);

    _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithFixedPriority(touchListener, -1);
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm running into a very similar issue.

Comment: Nevermind, worked, I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to return `true` at the end of the `onTouchBegan` method.

I was having the same issue: only `onTouchBegan` would fire, but not `onTouchMoved` or any of the others. I guess it's the boolean for whether or not the touch event keeps propagating, similar to the event structure in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the correction (@Ohthepain), I must have mixed it up with something else!

Here is the what I think is wrong with your code

```
auto touchListener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
touchListener->setSwallowTouches(true);
touchListener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(LevelOneScene::onTap, this);

touchListener->onTouchMoved = CC_CALLBACK_2(LevelOneScene::onTouchMoved, this);

_eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithFixedPriority(touchListener, -1);
```

Should be something like

```
auto dispatcher = Director::getInstance()->getEventDispatcher();
auto touchListener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();

touchListener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(LevelOneScene::onTap, this);

touchListener->onTouchMoved = CC_CALLBACK_2(LevelOneScene::onTouchMoved, this);

//THIS LINE
dispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(touchListener, this);
```

The last line is where I see a problem.

Comment: The 'virtual' keyword only needs to be in the base class. Adding 'virtual' to the derived class will only allow classes that inherit the LevelOneScene class to override these methods.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your handlers take Event* as their second parameter, but your 'this' pointers are of type LevelOneScene*.

I would do something like this:

```
// Create the upvalue - yes, this line is necessary!
LevelOneScene* sceneArg = this;
touchListener->onTouchMoved = [sceneArg](Touch* touch, Event* event)->bool {
            sceneArg->ccTouchBegan(touch, event);
        };
```